# How to write query for search the items using linq to sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

in my form two textboxes are there one for state and one for country.
if user enter only state based on states available in database i need to display items.if only country enters need to get matching country items from database.if both are  enter need to display matching state and country items in my view.please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, You want to filter Items according to state and country entered.

I assuming you have a database table, which storing items information and you have state and country fields also there, and you want to exact match of country or state.

Then you can try this.

```
var country = txtCountry.Text.Trim();
var state = txtState.Text.Trim();

var items = (from item in itemTable
            where (country == "" || item.country == country)
            &&    (state == "" || item.state == state)
            select item).ToList();
```

or you want to match country or state containing.

```
var items = (from item in itemTable
            where (country == "" || item.country.Contains(country))
            &&    (state == "" || item.state.Contains(state))
            select item).ToList();
```